# What do i need to override in a Model or Field in order to have a custom string representation for the admin site in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm using a custom dict field as the primary key for a model:

```
class Data(models.Model):
    _id = DictField(default={}, primary_key=True, db_column='_id')
```

If i want to edit an object, i get this link:

```
http://localhost:8000/admin/managerapp/data/OrderedDict(%5B('key1',%20'value1'),%20('key2',%20'value2')%5D)/change/
```

Which probably means that DictField isn't written very well, as django doesn't know how to serialize it.

What do i need to override Data or DictField and what methods in order to tell django how it can transform the dict `{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}` into a string and how can it transform that string back into the dict again?

I'm not very good at django internals and i don't know what keywords to search for.

Comment: A dict seems like a bad choice for a primary key, why not use the default auto-incrementing integer field as the primary key and just add a unique constraint in the dict field?

Comment: Agreed, this is not a good key. It's not really even a good idea as a unique field. Whatever data you have in there that needs to be unique should be split out into its own field(s); if it's variable but needs to be unique, you could use [EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model), though that should be a last resort.

Comment: I know dict might seem a bad choice for a primary key, but i'm storing these objects in MongoDB, and it's okay. Can you answer my original question?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out after a while. I needed to override the DictField:

```
class MyDict(models.DictField):
    def to_python(self, value):
        # string to dict

    def from_db_value(self, value, *args):
        # dict to string

    def get_db_prep_save(self, value, connection):
        # just in case you need more checks
        return super(MyDict, self).get_db_prep_save(value, connection)

class Data(models.Model):
    _id = MyDict(default={}, primary_key=True, db_column='_id')
```